# Sort single table by occurrence of 0 or 1 in a column

Tags: mysql

Good day!
I have a table format:

```
id |   machine  | Location   | on_off |   date_time
----------------------------------------------------------
1  | MAZAK-H630 | Location12 |  1     | 2023-06-20 09:43:48
2  | MAZAK-H630 | Location12 |  0     | 2023-06-20 09:47:38
```

I want to get another table of the format from this table:

```
id | Machine   |  Location  |  START Date$Time   |    STOP Date$Time
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | MAZAK-H630 | Location12 | 2023-06-20 09:43:48 | 2023-06-20 09:47:38
2 | MAZAK-H630 | Location12 | 2023-06-20 09:47:51 | 2023-06-20 09:54:44
```

But there is another condition - if in this table there is no 0 with date and time in the "on / off" column, then it is necessary to assign the current date and time and display it in the query.

Here's what I did, but it's a bit different from what I expected.

```
SELECT id, machine, location, on_off,
IF(on_off=1, date_time, "\r") as start,
IF(on_off=0, date_time, "\r") as stop
FROM sensordata ORDER by machine, location, id;
```

```
id |  Machine   |   Location  | on/off |  START Date$Time    |   STOP Date$Time
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | MAZAK-H630 | Location12  |   1    | 2023-06-20 09:43:48 |         NULL
 2 | MAZAK-H630 | Location12  |   0    |         NULL        | 2023-06-20 09:47:38
```

I would appreciate any help...

Comment: Take a look onto window lag and lead